# How to make R package recommend a package hosted on GitHub?

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I'm developing an R package that works as a wrapper for functions from the parallel and Rhpc packages called [ctools](http://www.github.com/bamonroe/ctools). I know that if I want my package to require these packages I need to include them in the `Imports` section of the `DESCRIPTION` file. When installing my package, these packages will be installed from CRAN. Similarly I can put them in the `Suggests` section if they aren't required, but useful. These won't be installed with my package.

But, I've forked the Rhpc package and added a function that I use in my ctools package. How do I get my package to Suggest/Import this package from my GitHub repo so of instead of installing the Rhpc package, it executes `devtools::install_github("bamonroe/Rhpc")`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the manual (and quoting source here):

> @c DESCRIPTION field Additional_repositories
>
> The @samp{Additional_repositories} field is a comma-separated list of
>   repository URLs where the packages named in the other fields may be
>   found.  It is currently used by @command{R CMD check} to check that the
>   packages can be found, at least as source packages (which can be
>   installed on any platform).

You can add the package to `Suggests:` and point to additional repositories -- possibly created using [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html). There used to a package doing that, and IIRC there is another one doing it now but its name escaped me now.

*Edit:* Found it! See here in the [source DESCRIPTION file of RNeXML](https://github.com/ropensci/RNeXML/blob/master/DESCRIPTION#L16-L17) -- and note how the line disappears in the [posted DESCRIPTION on CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/RNeXML/index.html).  Better still, note how two of the packages in `Suggests:` are *not* listed a hyperlinks on CRAN. I thinks those come from the additional repos. And yes, rOpenSci uses [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) to manage that.

*Edit 2:* And just to close the loop, you (easily) use [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) to host such an additional repo on GitHub -- the prime use case for [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html).

*Edit 3:* RNeXML has dropped the additional repository, but the [github history](https://github.com/ropensci/RNeXML/blob/dc1e8c79cb85c213baca01370029773545e52bb5/DESCRIPTION#L17) still has it.

*Edit 4:* Currently (i.e. on 2020-03-13), the CRAN packages EMC, bcmaps, blkbox, broom.mixed, epikit, grattan, gtsummary, hurricaneexposure, memoise, multinomialeq, noaastormevents, pointblank, provSummarize, provViz, spData, swephR, tashu, taxadb, waveformbildar all list a field `Additional_repositories` containing a URL pointing to a `drat` repo.

Comment: Great stuff! I'm reading through your drat basics page now. So I create a repository on GitHub, potentially by forking your drat git repo, point to my newly created repository in the `Additional_repositories` field of my `DESCRIPTION` file, and then add my forked version of Rhpc to the suggests line like it was any other package? Not that it's a problem, but would I have to change the name of my forked Rhpc? It seems like there would be a namespace confusion between the CRAN version and mine.

Comment: Yes, in that case you probably want a different name for Rhpc or at least a higher number.  All depends a little on whether you alter the existing API or just extend it.  And yup, drat should do all that for you.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @NealFultz.  I will update the body of the answer.

Comment: Using the drat repository and linking to it via the `Additional_repositories:` is absolutely the best way I've seen to include a GitHub dependency.  (Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel!)  I went through a few iterations of various strategies before landing on the drat repo, and the drat repo simply works.  

Previously, I was trying to install the GH package to a temp folder, and updating the library search path to include the temp folder. While this worked locally, I always had issues with at least one OS checked by CRAN (and this was the method suggested by a CRAN reviewer).

Comment: Hi @DanielSjoberg thanks for the endorsement!  It so happens, and is little surprise, that I agree 100% as the _package mechansism_ is so well designed and tested that it delivers this robustly, whereas alternatives eventually flake out.  `#FriendsDontLetFriendsUseRemote`