# Remove test dependencies from R package

Tags: r, git, unit-testing, r-package

I'm developing an R package that has a shiny app as part of it. I have been trying to add testing for the shiny component, which means that I now have dependencies required for that testing.

However, they make life potentially difficult for users given their own dependencies, and for future CRAN submission, since they are only available on github.

Is there a method for only including test dependencies (and tests) on non-master branches? I can remove those tests and dependencies manually on the master branch as a possible solution, but doesn't seem at all ideal.

Comment: That's too complicated.  Just use the `Suggests:` mechanism and then _test_ if the package is present, else skip the test.

Comment: OK this is exactly what i've been looking for (and struggling to find). So in the test script, have an `if(require)` statement?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. I am sure there are a million examples.  I have some examples for use of `if (requireNamespace("PKG", quietly=TRUE)` in my packages code, but seemingly not in tests.  It is the same there too though.

Comment: There may well be a million examples, but I haven't found one that is addressing this particular situation yet... would be great to be pointed to one

Comment: https://github.com/ehrlinger/ggRFVignette/blob/51089bbfdfd23c5141375814e24235e2fc469d6b/tests/testthat/test_lint.R -- second hit at GH. Third hit is https://github.com/jennybc/repurrrsive/blob/0b543c9197bd763fedf43e12a77750a908a8090a/tests/testthat.R

Comment: OK, maybe I'm not explaining very well - my understanding is that that setup would not be OK for CRAN - Suggests dependencies still need to be available on CRAN, is that right? happy to go to chat if that makes this easier....

Comment: Come on now---this is all documented and has been discussed at length.  Search for Additional_repositories.  `Suggests` != `Depends` (or `Imports`).

Comment: OK, sorry Dirk.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105257/how-to-make-r-package-recommend-a-package-hosted-on-github/36105343#36105343

Comment: And to close this: I _like_ the idea behind your package and conditional testing.  I am simply trying to help you with something both _workable_ and _easier_ and _CRAN compatible_.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what I want, I've just been struggling to find something similar that's documented, but maybe part of the problem is even knowing the right terms to search