# R package building: How to import a function from a package not on CRAN

Tags: r, r-package

#### Problem

I am trying to import a function from a non-CRAN repo into my package. 
I know R searches CRAN for any package declared in the `Imports:` field of the `DESCRIPTION` file. Is there any way to, for example, import `function` from package 'notoncran', which is only on Github (or some other non-CRAN place).

#### Non-desirable workaround:

I've worked out a nondesirable workaround which would consist of bypassing the `Imports:` field completely by defining my function as something like:

```
myfun <- function(a,b){
    x <- require(notoncran)
    if(!x){
        print("installing notoncran because you don't have it...")
        devtools::install_github('repo/withpackage')
        require(notoncran)
    }
    ...
}
```

I don't like this idea out of principle as you are installing a/several packages(s) to some extent without the user's consent, from a potentially unregulated (theoretically dangerous) source. This also reduces the readability of the function to some extent by weighing the function down with administrative business. Lastly, this method would eventually require running `require()` or `library()`, throwing all of the package's functions into the user's namespace which is never ideal.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: You could include the functions you want to use in your package itself, e.g. by copying the script form github into your project in R. This way your package treats the functions like your own written package. Make sure to get approval from the original package owner and give them author credits somewhere.

Comment: You could also explicitly ask your user if they are okay with installing the package, perhaps reminding them of the dangers of doing so. If they respond favorably, then you can install the package and carry on.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105257/how-to-make-r-package-recommend-a-package-hosted-on-github?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A super easy trick is to add a ‘remotes’ field into our `DESCRIPTION` file specifying the username/package_name target of our target package on Github.

```
Remotes:
    github::User/PackageNotOnCRAN
Import:
    PackageNotOnCRAN
Suggests:
    devtools,
    testthat
```

Not only will this work very well for files on github (`github::`), but works for git, bitbucket, local packages and more.

[More information](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/devtools/vignettes/dependencies.html), [how I figured it out](https://mattkcole.com/2017/10/24/github_packages/).