# What is the correct way to handle Remote dependencies for R CMD check?

Tags: r, r-package, remotes

I'm trying to check a package with a dependency on a private repo stored on github that I'm specifying as a Remotes in the DESCRIPTION file. E.g.:

```
Imports: 
  dplyr, 
  .... 
Remotes: 
  geebioso/rpackage
```

I've already set the appropriate environment variables for installing from github and have checked that I can document and install my package locally using devtools (including the Remotes dependency).

When I run `rcmdcheck::rcmdcheck()` I get the following warning:

```
'::' or ':::' import not declared from: 'rpackage'
```

I'd like to get rid of this particular warning, but still keep `error_on='warning'` and  check the Imports dependencies.

What's the correct way to handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: R itself doesn't use the `Remotes:` information in the package description. That's only used by the `devtools/remotes` package. You can't pass the official R checks If you aren't using proper R packages guidelines. Does `devtools::check()` not check the things you are interested in?  What checks are you trying to perform exactly?

Comment: Use [drat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36105343/9406040)